# How to call imported class on Button press kivy

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to reorganise my code so it's not all in one py and kv file. I've created some logic for a 5-star review function which works fine when I put all the code within the `Reviews(Screen)` class and call the methods with `on_press: root.method()`. However, I don't know what to replace `root.method()` with when the code isn't located in the same class.

main.py file:

```
import kivy
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from reviews import Reviews
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window


class ReviewWindow(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        kv = Builder.load_file("kivy.kv")
        self.sm = WindowManager()

        screens = [ReviewWindow(name="reviews")]
        for screen in screens:
            self.sm.add_widget(screen)

        self.sm.current = "reviews"
        return self.sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

kivy.kv file:

```
<ReviewWindow>:
    name: "reviews"

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1

        GridLayout:

        GridLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            cols: 7
            Label:
            MDIconButton:
                icon: "star-outline"
                id: star_1
                on_press: root.star_1_pressed()
            MDIconButton:
                icon: "star-outline"
                id: star_2
                on_press: root.star_2_pressed()
            MDIconButton:
                icon: "star-outline"
                id: star_3
                on_press: root.star_3_pressed()
            MDIconButton:
                icon: "star-outline"
                id: star_4
                on_press: root.star_4_pressed()
            MDIconButton:
                icon: "star-outline"
                id: star_5
                on_press: root.star_5_pressed()
            Label:

        GridLayout:
            cols: 3
            Label:
            MDRaisedButton:
                text: "review"
                on_release: root.submit_review()
            Label:

        GridLayout:
```

reviews.py file:

```
from kivymd.uix.button import MDIconButton
from kivymd.toast import toast


class Reviews():
    review_number = None

    def star_1_pressed(self):
        self.review_number = 1
        self.clear_stars()
        self.ids.star_1.icon = "star"
        self.ids.star_1.theme_text_color = "Custom"
        self.ids.star_1.text_color = [1,0.843,0,1]

    def star_2_pressed(self):
        self.review_number = 2
        self.clear_stars()
        self.ids.star_1.icon = "star"
        self.ids.star_2.icon = "star"
        self.ids.star_1.theme_text_color = "Custom"
        self.ids.star_1.text_color = [1,0.843,0,1]
        self.ids.star_2.theme_text_color = "Custom"
        self.ids.star_2.text_color = [1,0.843,0,1]

    def star_3_pressed(self):
        self.review_number = 3
        self.clear_stars()
        self.ids.star_1.icon = "star"
        self.ids.star_2.icon = "star"
        self.ids.star_3.icon = "star"
        self.ids.star_1.theme_text_color = "Custom"
        self.ids.star_1.text_color = [1,0.843,0,1]
        self.ids.star_2.theme_text_color = "Custom"
        self.ids.star_2.text_color = [1,0.843,0,1]
        self.ids.star_3.theme_text_color = "Custom"
        self.ids.star_3.text_color = [1,0.843,0,1]

    def star_4_pressed(self):
        self.review_number = 4
        self.clear_stars()
        self.ids.star_1.icon = "star"
        self.ids.star_2.icon = "star"
        self.ids.star_3.icon = "star"
        self.ids.star_4.icon = "star"
        self.ids.star_1.theme_text_color = "Custom"
        self.ids.star_1.text_color = [1,0.843,0,1]
        self.ids.star_2.theme_text_color = "Custom"
        self.ids.star_2.text_color = [1,0.843,0,1]
        self.ids.star_3.theme_text_color = "Custom"
        self.ids.star_3.text_color = [1,0.843,0,1]
        self.ids.star_4.theme_text_color = "Custom"
        self.ids.star_4.text_color = [1,0.843,0,1]

    def star_5_pressed(self):
        self.review_number = 5
        self.clear_stars()
        self.ids.star_1.icon = "star"
        self.ids.star_2.icon = "star"
        self.ids.star_3.icon = "star"
        self.ids.star_4.icon = "star"
        self.ids.star_5.icon = "star"
        self.ids.star_1.theme_text_color = "Custom"
        self.ids.star_1.text_color = [1,0.843,0,1]
        self.ids.star_2.theme_text_color = "Custom"
        self.ids.star_2.text_color = [1,0.843,0,1]
        self.ids.star_3.theme_text_color = "Custom"
        self.ids.star_3.text_color = [1,0.843,0,1]
        self.ids.star_4.theme_text_color = "Custom"
        self.ids.star_4.text_color = [1,0.843,0,1]
        self.ids.star_5.theme_text_color = "Custom"
        self.ids.star_5.text_color = [1,0.843,0,1]

    def clear_stars(self):
        self.ids.star_1.theme_text_color = "Custom"
        self.ids.star_1.text_color = [0,0,0,1]
        self.ids.star_2.theme_text_color = "Custom"
        self.ids.star_2.text_color = [0,0,0,1]
        self.ids.star_3.theme_text_color = "Custom"
        self.ids.star_3.text_color = [0,0,0,1]
        self.ids.star_4.theme_text_color = "Custom"
        self.ids.star_4.text_color = [0,0,0,1]
        self.ids.star_5.theme_text_color = "Custom"
        self.ids.star_5.text_color = [0,0,0,1]

    def submit_review(self):
        if self.review_number:
            toast("{} star review given".format(self.review_number))
        else:
            toast("Please click a star")
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: ```AttributeError: 'Reviews' object has no attribute 'star_1_pressed'``` At the moment it's because there's no code in the ```Reviews(Screen)``` class but I don't know how I call the reviews.py file. Maybe I need to instantiate the ```Reviews()``` class like this: ```Reviews(Screen): review = Reviews()```

Comment: It looks like you are re-defining the `Reviews` class in your `main.py`. Try removing the definition of `Reviews` from `main.py`.

Comment: I've changed the name of the ```Reviews``` class in my ```main.py``` file so I'm not redefining it (rookie mistake) but that hasn't solved the problem. I still get the same error message as above (although it's now called ```ReviewWindow```). I know it's because I'm calling ```root.star_1_pressed``` but there is no ```star_1_pressed``` method in my ```ReviewWindow(Screen)``` class, the methods are in the imported ```Reviews``` class but I don't know how to access them.

Comment: You still need to keep `Reviews` in your 'kv`. The point of importing a class from another file is that you don't have to redefine the class. You just use the imported class.

Comment: But what do I need to change the ```on_press: root.star_1_pressed``` event to to be able to reference the ```star_1_pressed``` method in the imported file?

Comment: You should not need to change anything. If it is not working, you will need to post a [mcve].

Comment: Ok, I have updated my code to a MRE. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `reviews.py` change:

```
class Reviews():
```

to

```
class Reviews(Screen):
```

Then in your `kivy.kv` change:

```
<ReviewWindow>:
```

to

```
<Reviews>:
```

And finally, in your `main.py` you can eliminate the `ReviewWindow` class:

```
import kivy
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from reviews import Reviews


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        kv = Builder.load_file("kivy.kv")
        self.sm = WindowManager()

        screens = [Reviews(name="reviews")]
        for screen in screens:
            self.sm.add_widget(screen)

        self.sm.current = "reviews"
        return self.sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked and I see what I need to do in future now